# Parsing HTML source using a loop

Tags: c#, html

I have a little problem, I am trying to parse a HTML string in my code, but what i want it to do is split the individual numbers up with a space inbetween each number ie:- " ".

I have made this loop to get rid of the tags

```
char[] array = new char[source.Length];
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        bool inside = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            numberfori = i;
            char let = source[i];

            if (let == '<')
            {
                inside = true;
                continue;
            }
            if (let == '>')
            {
                inside = false;                    
                continue;

            }
            if (!inside)
            {
                array[arrayIndex] = let;
                Console.WriteLine(arrayIndex);
                arrayIndex++;
            }
        }
        return new string(array, 1, arrayIndex);
```

now this returns :-

201549.0717593/2203.5732.6719.4412.86

but i need  :-

2015 49.0 7 175 9 3/22 0 3.57 32.67 19.44 12.86

and here is the HTML code string the loop runs through for you to see so you know where i get it from:-

```
>2015</a></td><td class="text-right">49.0</td><td class="text-right">7</td><td class="text-right">175</td><td class="text-right">9</td><td class="text-right"><a href="/website/results/2361208" target="_blank">3/22</a></td><td class="text-right">0</td><td class="text-right">3.57</td><td class="text-right">32.67</td><td class="text-right">19.44</td><td class="text-right">12.86</td></tr><tr><td><a data
```

Eventually i want to put each of these numbers into their own variables but i need to split them first which is the first task one step at a time :)

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: thank you but i want to try and do it without installing this pack if it is possible? Ive already explored this but it is an unnecessary answer maybe for what i need?

Comment: Using a `StringBuilder` loop through your array and append each character plus a space.

Comment: You should just be able to add `array[arrayIndex] = ' '; arrayIndex++;` after your line `inside = false;`

Comment: thanks guys, ok now Iceman your reply worked best but i just have too many spaces inbetween each of the numbers ie:- 2015    49.0   7   175   9   3/22   0   3.57   32.67   19.44   12.86 but it does work, unless i can seperate them into varibales from there?

Comment: @Marca -- See my answer below.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just load it into an XElement object and traverse it?

Comment: I found this way much simpler to be honest for what i need Thraka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
if (let == '>')
{
    inside = false;   
    if (arrayIndex > 0 && array[arrayIndex - 1] != ' ')
    {
        array[arrayIndex] = ' '; 
        arrayIndex++;
    }
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! So simple yet for an awesome mind thank you so much everybody :)